# Doing an integration test of a python package

Tags: python-3.x, integration-testing, package, python-module

I have a package that I want to be able to test from another package or from a test module not in the same directory. For example I have a directory in the following structure...

```
Project/
|-- bin/
|   |-- project
|-- project/
|   |-- subpackage1/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- foo1.py
|   |   |-- foo2.py
|   |-- subpackage2/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- bar1.py
|   |   |-- bar2.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- main.py
|-- test/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_main.py
|   |-- test_subpackage1/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- test_foo1.py
|   |   |-- test_foo2.py
|   |-- test_subpackage2/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- test_bar1.py
|   |   |-- test_bar2.py
|-- setup.py
|-- README
```

My `test/test_main.py` wants to use `project.subpackage1.bar1` classes to test the project code. However, when I do an `import project.subpackage1.bar1` I get an error that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/Project/test/test_main.py", line 1, in <module> import project.subpackage1.bar1
ImportError: No module named project.subpackage1.bar1
```

I hear that you can add

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
```

But even with that I get the same error. Is there any way of being able to use a test package outside of the directory of where the project package is? Along with that, is this the correct way to do a integration test?